# Lazyload angular modules being loaded on another routes

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm using angular lazyloading to lazyload my modules and here is my routes:

```
  {
    pathMatch: 'full',
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/landing/home-page/home-page.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'web-design',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/landing/web-design/web-design.module').then(m => m.WebDesignModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'content',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/landing/content/content.module').then(m => m.ContentModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public/freelancer-profile/freelancer-profile.module').then(m => m.FreelancerProfileModule)
  },
  {
    canActivate: [LoginGuardService],
    path: 'panel',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/private/private.module').then(m => m.PrivateModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'freelancer',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/freelancer-search/freelancer-search.module').then(m => m.FreelancerSearchModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/landing/landing.module').then(m => m.LandingModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public/public.module').then(m => m.PublicModule)
  },
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/public/logging/logging.module').then(m => m.LoggingModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '404',
  }
];
```

but when i go to **/web-design** page in network javascript tab **content.module** and **freelancer-profile** are being loaded as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the problem is that you have to implement the *CanLoad* interface inside the **LoginGuardService** guard for the '*content*' path. For more information I give you the documentation of [CanLoad Interface](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad)

Comment: What is the point of LazyLoadModule if i should create gaurd for each route.